# How to make Laravel work asynchronously?

Tags: laravel, asynchronous, laravel-5, lumen, laravel-queue

I have written this piece of code in Laravel(Lumen) v5.6:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    // other code here
    $this->bigUglyFunction($comment);
    return response()->json($comment);
}
```

I'm expecting the *bigUglyFunction()* to take a significant amount of time to finish executing. But I want to return the Response as quickly as possible. So I need the program to pass control to the next line while it's also executing that function. Maybe Laravel Queues can be handy but I am not sure, and also I'm not much experienced in this area. I'm hoping someone could help me regarding how to make that method work asynchronously. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use jobs [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues)

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to queues
**Queues** [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues]

*It is one the best ways to implement the asyncronous nature on big tasks.*